# How do you go about saving objects into an SQLite database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, object

I am new to database's in general. I have been learning C# and at a point to start applying a database to my projects. I decided to start learning SQLite since from what I've read it is pretty simple to use and learn. I am confused on how to submit object into a database.

Example: I have a class that is a deck, in that class I have a list of Card, which is a separate class that has properties. I want to find away to save the List in the database. From what I can see you can only save text or integers? But I'm sure I must be wrong.

I've been searching for tutorials that save objects to SQLite but all I've found are tutorials that have super simple examples of storing a text and returning it. Can anyone explain to me how this is done, or direct me to reading material/tutorial that explains this?

I have had such a hard time figuring out databases, and it is frustrating! Everyone tells me how easy it is, but it looks so foreign to me. I don't know why I'm having such a hard time.

Comment: 1) Make the database, 2) Make the schema (table), 3) Connect to the database in c#, 4) Execute an SQL statement in c#. Which are you having problems with?

Comment: Are you already aware of the following: classes are tables in (relational) databases; each table row is an instance/object of a class; each column is a property of a class; each cell is a property value of an instance/object.

Comment: Also be aware that databases don't have to be relational. There are other types of databases that might be a better fit for your application ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) for instance).

Comment: You could also have a look at [EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/). It allows you to define your model (the classes) and can generate a database schema (the tables and their relations) automatically. EF will also generate the queries for you from C# code. EF also supports SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to make your life more complicated that it has to be.
ORM tools are the way forward for storing related objects into databases.

Since you use c# entity framework is one of them and very powerful.
See this tutorial for SQLite.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli